# camel-jetty: Buffering capacity exceeded

Tags: apache-camel, jetty

I'm using the following route:

```
<route>
    <from uri="file:...
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
          <constant>PUT</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="jetty:http://localhost:55556/extract?restletMethod=PUT"/>
    <to uri="ejb:java:global/Abc/Bean?method=doSomething(${body}, ${headers})"/>
</route>
```

Endpoint:

```
 public InputStream extract(@Body InputStream inputStream, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) throws Exception {

    byte[] b = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

    // do some stuff

    headers.put("extraction", ...);

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
}
```

If the file size exceeds 2 MB the following exception occurs:
([Camel-Jetty http proxy + large response data casue issue: Buffering capacity exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546655/camel-jetty-http-proxy-large-response-data-casue-issue-buffering-capacity-exc))

```
JettyClient failed cause by: Buffering capacity exceeded. Exchange[ID-debianjk-scsynergy-local-43219-1479191420664-41-8]. Caused by: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Buffering capacity exceeded]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9.doTaskCompleted(JettyContentExchange9.java:156)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyContentExchange9$2.onComplete(JettyContentExchange9.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:453)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:434)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseContent(HttpReceiver.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.content(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.content(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseContent(HttpParser.java:1472)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1245)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:89)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:123)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffering capacity exceeded
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.BufferingResponseListener.onContent(BufferingResponseListener.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.Response$Listener$Adapter.onContent(Response.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyContent(ResponseNotifier.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.access$100(ResponseNotifier.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier$ContentCallback.process(ResponseNotifier.java:274)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:208)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyContent(ResponseNotifier.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseContent(HttpReceiver.java:322)
        ... 13 more
```

Questions:

Is there a way to avoid this buffering issue? (Maybe by using another component instead of jetty?)

Since the body is not changed in the jetty-endpoint I was wondering if it's possible to "bypass" the body directly to the next endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<to uri="http://localhost:55556/extract?restletMethod=PUT"/>` fixed it for me.